# Load content of the tabs to shorten the page loading

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I am using the jQuery UI tabs to embed different social widgets in each tab using JS and jQuery. I trying to rebuild script to shorten the page loading because for now jQuery UI tabs are loading all external JS files from all tabs at page start. I want to load content of active tab on click.

Is this possible?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JakubSkowronski/gn7k719u/33/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //When page loads...
  $(".tab-content").hide(); //Hide all content
  $(".tabs tab-links a:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
  $(".tabs .tab-content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

  //On Click Event
  $(".tabs .tab-links a").click(function() {

    $(".tabs .tab-content .tab").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $(".tabs .tab-content .tab").hide(); //Hide all tab content

    var activeTab = $(this).attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content

    if ($(activeTab).html() == '') {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/url/to/post',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(content) {
          $(activeTab).html(content);
        }
      });
    }

    $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
    return false;
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. About as simple as I could get it.  It uses the tab number and the associated div id to figure out what file to load and what div it goes in.

I created 3 content html files for each section call fragment0.html, fragment1.hml and fragment2.html.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link href="Scripts/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Scripts/jquery-ui.theme.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/Knockout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#tabs").tabs({
                    activate: function (t, b) {
                        var newId = b.newPanel[0].id;
                        if($("#" + newId).children().length == 0){
                            doAjax(newId);
                        }
                    }
                });
                doAjax("fragment0");
            });

            function doAjax(pageName) {
                $.ajax({
                    url:pageName + ".html",
                    error: function () {
                        $('#info').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
                    },
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function (data, rq) {
                        var d = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active");
                        $("#fragment" + d).html(data);
                    },
                    type: 'GET'
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div id="info"></div>
            <div id="tabs">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#fragment0"><span>One</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#fragment1"><span>Two</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#fragment2"><span>Three</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="fragment0"></div>
                <div id="fragment1"></div>
                <div id="fragment2"></div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$( ".selector" ).tabs({

  activate: function( event, ui ) {
    // put code here to see if tab is loaded if not, load it.
  }

});
// then add code here to load the first tab.




});
```

Comment: If you are still stuck later on today, I can sketch out a better reply when I get home from work.